# Remove duplicate and original row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to drop all records which have a duplicate from the below DataFrame `df`.

```
  sales_id sales_line
    100      1
    100      1
    200      1
    300      2
    300      2
    400      3
    500      1
    500      1
    600      5
```

The expected output I am trying to achieve is seen below.

```
sales_id sales_line
    200      1
    400      3
    600      5
```

Any assistance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you expect `200 1` and not `500 1` which is the last entry for sales_line = 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep=False` for remove  duplicates in all columns:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print (df)
   sales_id  sales_line
2       200           1
5       400           3
8       600           5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `drop_duplicates(self, subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)`

In your case, the important bit of the function is the `keep=False`.

```py
import pandas as pd


data = { 'sales_id' : [100, 100, 200, 300, 300, 400, 500, 500, 600], 'sales_line' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('Source DataFrame:\n', df)

df_dropped = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['sales_id', 'sales_line'], keep=False)
print('Result DataFrame:\n', df_dropped)
```

Answer (score 1):

## dropping ALL duplicte values

```
data.drop_duplicates(keep = False, inplace = True)
```

This would give you the expected output